# Why gcd(r,(p-1)/r) needs to be 1 in benaloh cryptosystem

Tags: encryption, public-key, homomorphic-encryption

I recently discovered the benaloh cryptosystem.
I am working with the system as it is discribed in the following link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benaloh_cryptosystem

However I need some help in order to understand why we need
\begin{equation}
{gcd(r,(p-1)/r)} 
\end{equation}

As far as I understand the condition
\begin{equation}
r \mid (p-1) 
\end{equation}
guarantees the existence of the subgroup of order (p-1)/r which contains the r-residues.

The third condition

\begin{equation}
{gcd(r,(q-1))} 
\end{equation}

allows us to say that there are

\begin{equation}
\mid \mathbb{Z}_n^* \mid /r
\end{equation}
r-residues mod n.

what does the other condition add?

Comment: You need those conditions to be sure that $r^2 \not | \phi(n)$

Comment: why is this important here?

Comment: otherwise your secret key $x$ would be a $r$-residue. and the decryption would not work. I'll try to write down the whole in a complete answer during next weekend.

Answer (score -1):

$gcd(r,(p-1)/r)$ needs to be $1$ in Benaloh cryptosystem that mean that $(r)$ and $(p-1)$ are preliminary among them.

Comment: sorry i dont understand your answer. Could you please explain what do you mean by preliminary among them?

Comment: it's mean they have to be prime between them e.g 9 and 26 are prime between them.

Comment: then what you say is not true. $gcd(r,(p−1)/r)$ only says that $r$ and $(p-1)/r$ are prime between them. But surely not that $r$ and $p-1$ are prime between them (which is not the case by the way).  This doesn't seem to be an answer to my initial question why we need this condition.

Comment: yep, i got you , u want to know why this condition is set up, the authors of this algorithm set this condition which is
gcd(r,(p−1)/r)=gcd(r,p−1)=1 maybe u have just to read the exect article. for all what i know, it's necessary for the algorithm to work correctly, u may want to see the work of "Benaloh's Dense Probabilistic Encryption Revisited"
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.2991.pdf